# New C++/C syntax

Tags: c++, c

what does the code below mean? What does the `&` symbol signify?

```
bool x = true;
x& = (1 || 0);
```

Comment: **Most** of your tags were utterly bogus. Don't spam irrelevant tags.

Comment: It signifies poor formatting.

Comment: I think that's meant to be a `&=`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`x& = (1 || 0);` is supposed to be `x &= (1 || 0);` which means `x = x & (1 || 0);` which means `x = x & 1` which means it ands the least significant bit.

Answer (score 3):

```
x& = (1 || 0);
//^space cannot be here
```

is wrong, there should be no space between `&` and `=`.

If you mean `&=` (compound operator), then the expression means:

```
x = x & (1 ||0);
```

first do logical `or` then do `bit and`. It is equivalent to:

```
x = x & 1;
```